# Jest snapshot test fails because adds ShallowWrapper to the snapshot

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

Testing with this file, and shallow rendering with enzyme:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import useStore from "redux-mock-store";

import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import { initUserState } from "../../reducers/user";
import { initProjectsState } from "../../reducers/projects";
import { initPagesState } from "../../reducers/pages";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

describe('Dashboard', () => {

    const middlewares = [ thunk ];

    const setStore = useStore(middlewares);

    const store = setStore({
        user: initUserState,
        projects: initProjectsState,
        pages: initPagesState
    });

    it('should render correctly', () => {
        const Component = shallow(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Dashboard />
            </Provider>
        );

        expect(Component).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Returns this error to the terminal:

```
  ● Dashboard › should render correc
tly

    expect(received).toMatchSnapshot
()

    Snapshot name: `Dashboard should
 render correctly 1`

    - Snapshot
    + Received

    - <ContextProvider
    -   value={
    -     Object {
    -       "store": Object {
    -         "clearActions": [Function],
    -         "dispatch": [Function],
    -         "getActions": [Function],
    -         "getState": [Function],
    -         "replaceReducer": [Function],
    -         "subscribe": [Function],
    -       },
    -       "subscription": Subscription {
    -         "handleChangeWrapper": [Function],
    -         "listeners": Object {
    -           "notify": [Function],
    -         },
    -         "onStateChange": [Function],
    -         "parentSub": undefined,
    -         "store": Object {
    -           "clearActions": [Function],
    -           "dispatch": [Function],
    -           "getActions": [Function],
    -           "getState": [Function],
    -           "replaceReducer": [Function],
    -           "subscribe": [Function],
    -         },
    -         "unsubscribe": null,
    -       },
    -     }
    -   }
    - >
    -   <Dashboard />
    - </ContextProvider>
    + ShallowWrapper {}
```

I'm not sure if it's expected or not, but it fails the test so it shouldn't be right. I tried with `enzyme.mount`, and with `enzyme.shallow` as well, but both returns the same wrapper error. Maybe it's because of the redux `Provider`, but I saw using this approach in many places.

What am I doing wrong, and how to fix it?